# How to serve part of a file with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, x-accel-redirect

I'm using [X-Accel](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) to serve protected content, using X-Accel-Redirect.

Is it possible to serve only a part of the file? for example, bytes range 0-x, or first 5 minutes of a video (my final goal)

It's important to do that on the server-side, so the client will not have access to the rest of the file.

Currently this is how I send the whole file:

```yaml
X-Accel-Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: {file_size}
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.mp4"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Accel-Buffering: yes
X-Accel-Redirect: /protected/myfile.mp4
```

Nginx conf:

```
location /protected {
    internal;
    alias /dir/of/protected/files/;
    if_modified_since off;
    output_buffers 2 1m;
    open_file_cache max=50000 inactive=10m;
    open_file_cache_valid 15m;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
    open_file_cache_errors off;
}
```

Comment: See: https://serverfault.com/questions/172789/nginx-to-serve-only-part-of-a-file/172820

Comment: @ofirule 2nd answer looks interesting. Is it possible to use `limit_rate_after` in `X-Accel-Redirect`?

Comment: A massive hack would be to proxy nginx to itself and inject the Range header

Comment: @stringy05 as long as it works and more efficient than via a script (PHP)... can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

The massive hack would be to use nginx to proxy to itself with a `Range` header that would limit the request to a range of bytes

something like this (not tested so this probably wont work, but the idea should work):

```
{ 

    ... snip config ...

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /html;
                index index.html;

        location / {

            proxy_pass http://localhost/content;
            add_header Range btyes=0,100000;
        }

        location /content {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested `Slice` and `X-Accel` together. If each file can have a different limit defined by the backend you might configure  [Slice](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/slice/) in the location and send the limit with the `X-Accel-Redirect` URL as below:

```
X-Accel-Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: {file_size}
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.mp4"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Accel-Buffering: yes
X-Accel-Redirect: /protected/myfile.mp4?s=0&e=$PHP_VAR
```

Nginx.conf

```
location /protected {
    slice; # enable slicing
    slice_start_arg s;
    slice_end_arg e;

    internal;
    alias /dir/of/protected/files/;
    if_modified_since off;
    output_buffers 2 1m;
    open_file_cache max=50000 inactive=10m;
    open_file_cache_valid 15m;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
    open_file_cache_errors off;
}
```

**A global file limit**

You would need to redirect the original request including the Slice parameters to truncate the file being served.

Nginx conf:

```
location /sample {
    slice; # enable slicing
    slice_start_arg s;
    slice_end_arg e;

    internal;
    alias /dir/of/protected/files/;
    if_modified_since off;
    output_buffers 2 1m;
    open_file_cache max=50000 inactive=10m;
    open_file_cache_valid 15m;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
    open_file_cache_errors off;
}

location /protected {
    rewrite ^ /sample&s=0&e=1024; # replace for the desired file limit in bytes
}
```

If the `rewrite` directive above doesn't work, I suggest the following option using `proxy_pass`.

```
location /protected {
    set $file_limit 1024 # replace for the desired file limit in bytes
    set $delimiter "";
    if ($is_args) {
        set $delimiter "&";
    }
    set $args $args${delimiter}s=0&e=$file_limit;
    proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1/sample; 
}
```

Comment: is there a way to change the `$file_limit` from the script? (php) like sending it as a parameter? It changes from file to file.

Comment: @HTMHell I've edited the answer to include the scenario of the limit being defined by the backend foe each file.

Comment: I'm getting the following error message: `nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "slice" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:128` line 128 is `slice;`

Comment: I googled the slice module, and there's another link for [slice](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_slice_module.html) with a different syntax. What's the differences between the two?

Comment: That's interesting. The page you refer belongs to Nginx itself: "This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the `--with-http_slice_module` configuration parameter.". It requires a `size` parameter and will chop the file in equal chunks sending `Range` HTTP headers to the backend. I understand this not what you want. The page I referred you points to a different module that you need to build yourself. Here is the repo: https://github.com/alibaba/nginx-http-slice/blob/master/README.md